# How does an authoritatve domain know when you IP address changes?

Tags: email, domain, windows-sbs

I have a SBS server running Exchange 2010.  We had a domain and decided to change it.  We would like to allow emails to come into the server from both the new and old domain.

I read on the tech forums that I could create an accepted domain in the exchange console to allow the emails to come in.

My question is this though.  Currently the SBS server is doing the work to keep the IP address changes from the ISP in sync with the domain registrar.  I read that SBS will only allow one domain to be set up at one time.  With the dynamic IP setting, I assume if my IP ever changes then it would update the DNS records and keep the two talking.

I set up the accepted domain in the exchange console, but how does the connection between the accepted domain work in relation to the old, now non managed(?) domain?

Thanks for the help, this is new territory for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just for a moment, forget the Windows server.

You have two domains. To accept email each domain must have one or more `MX` records in the DNS maintained by your registrar. These records point to the server names that accept mail for the domain. The server address can, potentially, be *any* server on the Internet. It doesn't have to be a server in the same domain. MX records for different domains can point to the same server.

The servers in turn have address records (`A` records) that link the name of the server to it's IP address. Mostly, for servers, a static IP address is used, but...

Remember that SBS server? From what you say it's maintaining the `A` record relating to its IP address by some communication between itself and your registrar. There are many ways this might happen, and you haven't given any details, so we'll assume that your registrar is maintaining an accurate `A` record and IP address.

If you set the MX records for both your domains to point to the server name that is maintained by your registrar then mail for both domains will be delivered to that server.

However, the Exchange server (your mail server software) must told which domains it should handle. Mostly, an SBS server will handle just one, but it can be configured to handle two or more. If the server isn't properly configured it will just reject any mail that arrives for a domain it doesn't recognise.

Properly set up, the sequence of events is this:

- Remote user creates email and sends it to their server.
- Remote server extracts the domain of the target address and looks up the MX record
  for it.
- From the MX record, the remote server finds the `A` record,
  and thence the IP address of the destination server.
- The remote server contacts your SBS server at that address and sends the message.
- Your server examines the domain in the destination address of the incoming
  message and checks it against it's configured list.
- Messages for matched domains are accepted and delivered to the recipients'
  mailbox. Messages for unmatched domains are rejected.

BTW, don't confuse the Domain your Windows network is using with the DNS domain visible on the Internet. Although they might have similar names they are entirely separate and different things.